# Using Python logging module in C

Tags: python, c, python-2.7

I am interested in using the Python logging module in a C program.  I've tried reading over the documentation at http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html , but I'm rather stuck.

This is what I want to accomplish (Python equivalent):

```
import logging, logging.handlers
logger = logging.getLogger('')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
socketHandler = logging.handlers.SocketHandler('localhost', logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT)
logger.addHandler(socketHandler)
logger.debug("whats up, doc?")
```

This is what I attempted in C:

```
PyObject *logging, *get_logger, *pValue, *set_level, *strargs;
*logging = PyImport_ImportModule("logging")
*get_logger = PyObject_GetAttrString(logging, "getLogger")
*pValue = PyObject_CallObject(get_logger, NULL)
*set_level = PyObject_GetAttrString(logging, "setLevel")
*strargs = PyString_FromString("logging.DEBUG")
pValue = PyObject_CallObject(set_level, strargs);
```

I'm not sure how to create the socketHandler, though.  Any hints?  Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to ultimately accomplish? If you're writing a C library for Python, a library has no business setting up the logger, that should be done by the main program. If you're writing a C program that embeds Python, you could still handle the setup by eval-ing a bit of Python code instead of doing the whole thing in C.

Comment: I am writing a C program that embeds Python.  In my initial iteration, I just tried using PyRun_SimpleString(...), but I am unable to pass arguments AFAIK.  So if I wanted to call logger.debug with SimpleString, it has to be hardcoded in.

Comment: There's a whole mess of `PyRun_X` functions, some let you pass in values into the context. Not like you want any of those, because then you can't work with the interpreter thus setup anymore, if I read the docs right. Also, what parameters do you need to setup the logger? (By setup I mean "everything before the last `logger.debug(...)` call")

Comment: The parameters are in my Python snippet:  I need to attach a SocketHandler as well as setting the logger level.

Comment: Okay but it's not clear which of the many values in your Python snippet can't be hardcoded or read from a configuration file from the Python code.

Comment: Everything before the logger.debug(...) command could either be hardcoded or read from a configuration file.  They don't change throughout the course of my program.

Answer (score 1):

In the Python C API, just as in Python, "Creating an object" is just calling its type

Unfortunately, doing all the `getattr` stuff in C is really annoying. Depending on what you want to do from C, you can provide a bunch of helper modules which you pass over to C at import time (see https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-python-client/blob/master/couchbase/_bootstrap.py for an example).

In any event, Python is a really simple language, both inside and out. Thus, let's break this down.

```
socketHandler = logging.handlers.SocketHandler('localhost', logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT)
```

PEP-7 says C89, but it's easier to show it in C99:

```
PyObject *logging = PyImport_ImportModule("logging");
PyObject *handlers = PyObject_GetAttrString(logging, "handlers");
```

Now, build the socket handler. From the C API, calling something can be 
done with PyObject_CallObject, which works on anything that has `__call__`  defined
First, though, you need to build thr arguments..

```
PyObject *sh_ctor = PyObject_GetAttrString(handlers, "SocketHandler");
PyObject *args = Py_BuildValue("(si)", "localhost", DEFAULT_LOGGING_PORT)
PyObject *sh_instance = PyObject_CallObject(sh_ctor, args);
```

I'm not going to show how to do arg building here, or even proper error checking or refcounting. Note that in the C API, if a function fails, it returns `NULL` and raises an exception (unless noted otherwise).

What I'd recommend in reality is figure out how much of the `logging` module you actually need to use from C, and wrap that functionality in a simpler subset which you can call from C. See the `_bootstrap.py` module i linked to above.